# How to set decimal precision up to 6 digits for a column in datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable, precision

In my application, for Currency Analysis I have to deal with numbers in 7,6 format. 7 digits before the decimal format and 6 digits after the decimal point. ***Example:*** 1234567.123456

I am getting the exchange rates from the user and sending it to backend through the C# code. I have used the following datatable to store the rates and sending it to the SP.

```
DataTable structureTable = new DataTable("CurrencyAnalysis");
    structureTable.Columns.Add("CurrentYearRate", typeof(decimal));
    structureTable.Columns.Add("PriorYearRate", typeof(decimal));
```

Now, the issue is whenever I try to save a number with 6 digits after the decimal point, only the first two digits after the decimal points are getting saved. 
i.e, if I save ***1234567.123456***, only ***123456.12*** is getting saved.

It takes only two precision. How can I set decimal precision for that column so that it can take up to 6 digits to the right of the decimal point?

Application background:

- C# Web application with HTML5 and AngularJS
- SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Define database value as `decimal(18,6)` The first value`(18)` is the precision and the second `(6)` is the scale, so `(18,6)` is essentially 18 digits with 6 digits after the decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

Define it in database as `decimal(18,6)`

Answer (score 0):

On Sql Server you have option with those 3 data type :

Float - 32 bit (7 digits)

Decimal - 128 bit (28-29 significant digits)

Check if you choose : `decimal(18,2)` it might be why you have 2 decimal.

You can store your numbers as Float too.